# Qt5 QML, why are onHeightChanged and onWidthChanged called without change?

Tags: qml, qt5

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property int lastW: 0
    property int lastH: 0

    function doSomething()
    {
        if (lastW == width && lastH == height)
            console.log("width & height same as last time")

        lastW = width;
        lastH = height;
    }

    onHeightChanged: doSomething();
    onWidthChanged: doSomething();
}
```

Why is `doSomething` called with no change in width and height (except for once at the start). When i resize the window, i get the console log message.

running windows 8.1

Comment: ? Because the height and width is changed when you resizing the window. Do I missunderstood your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doSomething` runs every time `width` **or** `height` of the `ApplicationWindow` changes. The window may change size in both dimensions simultaneously. If in one moment size change from 100x100 to 101x101 then both signals `widthChanged` and `heightChanged` will be emitted for `width=101` and `height=101`. That is why `console.log("width & height same as last time")` is being executed despite the fact that at the first glance this should never happen.

---

To comment on `doSomething` being run on the start. For me `doSomething` never fires unless I resize window. If for you it does fire when application starts it may be because for a short moment the `ApplicationWindow` has some initial size (for example 0x0) and just after that it changes size to 640x480 and `doSomething` runs.

---

In some rare cases what I have written above may not be valid. You can try to resize `ApplicationWindow` in one dimension only and still sometimes `changed` signal will occur twice for the same value. My guess is that in those cases value has changed so fast that while triggering `changed` twice in QML you read only the second value.

I suspect that it works like this:
`width=100` then quickly changes value to `101` fires `changed`, changes to `102` and again `changed` is fired. After that the QML signals are being executed. Now you receive two `changed` signals but in both you read value `102`.

Comment: thank you. You are correct. it must call _both_ if there is a simultaneous change.